# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Bootstrap 5 - Jquery Modal hide is no longer working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-5

Good Day Everyone

I updated my Bootstrap from version 4.5 to 5.0, then I found out that there are changes specially the version 5 is not jquery reliable, now I change the codes that has affect after the upgrade, and most of them are in Modal popup, I tried this code below to show the modal.

```
    var MyModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("ModalSample"), {backdrop:'static',keyboard:false});
MyModal.show();
```

It works fine but for when I tried to close it using this.

```
MyModal.hide();
```

This does not work, I have javascript methods that needs to close the Modal popup, I tried to search it on the internet but most of them are for version 4 which is I used before I upgrade it.

I hope you can help me on this, as most of my scripts calling the Modal hide function.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Well, what you've tried matches the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#hide so there must be something else causing it, eg `MyModal` variable not defined where you call it.  Any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible code snippet?